# GLSL memoryBarrier()

Tags: opengl, glsl, gpu, memory-barriers

OpenGL red book version 8 (GL 4.3) example 11.19 places a `imageLoad()` in a while loop, keep polling until at least one fragment of the previous primitive has updated this value. This book says

> Example 11.19 shows a very simple use case for memory barriers. It allows
>   some level of ordering between fragments to be ensured. At the top of
>   `functionUsingBarriers()`, a simple loop is used to wait for the contents
>   of a memory location to reach our current primitive ID. **Because we know
>   that no two fragments from the same primitive can land on the same
>   pixel, we know that when we’re executing the code in the body of the
>   function, at least one fragment from the previous primitive has been
>   processed**. We then go about modifying the contents of memory at our
>   fragment’s location using nonatomic operations. We signal to other shader
>   invocations that we are done by writing to the shared memory location
>   originally polled at the top of the function.
>
> To ensure that our modified image contents are written back to memory
>   before other shader invocations start into the body of the function, we use
>   a call to memoryBarrier between updates of the color image and the
>   primitive counter to enforce ordering.

However, GL spec 4.3 says

> having one invocation poll memory written by another invocation assumes that the other invocation has been launched and can complete its writes

So how can we assure that fragment invocations of the previous primitive have been launched and completed its writes?

Post the src code

```
#version 420 core

layout (rgba32f} uniform coherent image2D my_image;

// Declaration of function
void functionUsingBarriers(coherent uimageBuffer i)

{

    uint val;

    // This loop essentially waits until at least one fragment from
    // an earlier primitive (that is, one with gl_PrimitiveID - 1)
    // has reached the end of this function point. Note that this is
    // not a robust loop as not every primitive will generate
    // fragments.
    do
    {
        val = imageLoad(i, 0).x;
    } while (val != gl_PrimitiveID);

    // At this point, we can load data from another global image
    vec4 frag = imageLoad(my_image, gl_FragCoord.xy);

    // Operate on it...
    frag *= 0.1234;
    frag = pow(frag, 2.2);

    // Write it back to memory
    imageStore(my_image, gl_FragCoord.xy, frag);

    // Now, we’re about to signal that we’re done with processing
    // the pixel. We need to ensure that all stores thus far have
    // been posted to memory. So, we insert a memory barrier.
    memoryBarrier();

    // Now we write back into the original "primitive count" memory
    // to signal that we have reached this point. The stores
    // resulting from processing "my_image" will have reached memory
    // before this store is committed due to the barrier.
    imageStore(i, 0, gl_PrimitiveID + 1);

    // Now issue another barrier to ensure that the results of the
    // image store are committed to memory before this shader
    // invocation ends.
    memoryBarrier();
}
```

Comment: Not all of us have this book. Can you actually provide us with the specific details of what is going on in this example? In particular, what does "previous primitive" mean?

Comment: Hi Nicol, I have updated the question. Please reread it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code (and the text that accompanies it) is errant nonsense. Consider this statement:

> Because we know that no two fragments from the same primitive can land on the same pixel, we know that when we’re executing the code in the body of the function, at least one fragment from the previous primitive has been processed.

Even if we assume that the primitives in the mesh are not overlapping (hardly a reasonable assumption in general), that means precisely *nothing* about the GPU's distribution of work across primitives.

The OpenGL specification makes this clear:

> The relative order of invocations of the same shader type are undefined. A
>   store issued by a shader when working on primitive B might complete prior
>   to a store for primitive A, even if primitive A is specified prior to primitive
>   B. This applies even to fragment shaders; while fragment shader outputs
>   are always written to the framebuffer in primitive order, stores executed by
>   fragment shader invocations are not.
>
> ...
>
> The above limitations on shader invocation order also make some forms of
>   synchronization between shader invocations within a single set of primitives unimplementable. For example, having one invocation poll memory written by another invocation assumes that the other invocation has been launched and can complete
>   its writes. The only case where such a guarantee is made is when the inputs of
>   one shader invocation are generated from the outputs of a shader invocation in a
>   previous stage.

Yes, the OpenGL specification *specifically called this out* as something which you *cannot do*. I have no idea how that got into an official OpenGL book, but your instincts are correct: it's completely wrong. This is in fact why ARB_fragment_shader_interlock exists: because otherwise, you could not do such a thing.

Comment: Thanks very much. Your clarifications sustain my suspicion. I doubted my instincts as this code example comes from authoritative OpenGL red book!